# How to import React object: elements via module.exports and render inside component?

Tags: reactjs, react-css-modules

I am trying to import and render an object:property of type React 'element' from external file and import it using module.exports into another file containing a Component and render it inside the Component. The component has previously been called 3 times, to create 3 columns and fill them with text.

This works when importing 'text' however I cannot get it to work importing a React 'element'.

What do I need to do to render the imported React 'element'? I am also using css-modules. Below is the code. Thanks:-

```
(File: column.css)
.default {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 32%;
  height: auto;
}

.red  {
  composes: default;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2%;
  background-color: red;
}

.green  {
  composes: default;
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  composes: default;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 2%;
  background-color: white;
}


(File: Home.js)
import React from 'react'
import Column from '../components/Column'
import styles from './home.css'

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <Column style = {'red'} content={'firstColumn'}/>
        <Column style = {'green'} content={'secondColumn'}/>
        <Column style = {'blue'} content={'thirdColumn'}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


(File: Column.js)
import React from 'react'
import style from './column.css'
const contents = require( '../components/content')

export default class Column extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className={style[this.props.style]}>
          {contents[this.props.content]}
        </div>
    )
  }
}


(File: content.js)
import React from "react"

module.exports = {
  firstColumn: text,
  secondColumn: "This text is rendered",
  thirdColumn: "This text is rendered",
}

const text = <p>This element text is NOT rendered</p>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hm ... shouldn't your `content.js` looks like:

```
const text = <p>This element text is NOT rendered</p>;

module.exports = {
  firstColumn: text,
  secondColumn: "This text is rendered",
  thirdColumn: "This text is rendered",
}
```

the `text` variable is not hoisted so you're exporting `undefined` as `firstColumn`.